# get folder structure using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file to list the folder structure in one of the shared drive. I want the output in this format-

```
Parent folder/directory at level 0       Child folder/directory at level 1

       ....                                       .....
Child folder/directory at level 1       Child folder/directory at level 2

      .....                                      .....
```

I want the complete path of the folder. Can someone please share any information on how to achieve this.
I tried

```
echo off
for /d %%a in (*.*) do dir /on "%%a" >> get_list.txt
```

but this only gives the children at first level and also only the folder name. However, I want it to iterate through all the levels and want the entire path.

Comment: I tried echo off
for /d %%a in (*.*) do dir /on "%%a" >> get_list.txt   but this only gives the children at first level and also only the folder name. However, I want it to iterate through all the levels and want the entire path.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling it to look at subfolders as well, and not telling it to list only directories.

This will work (you'll need to tinker some with the output):

```
dir /ad /on /s
```

You'll get entries for each folder for `.` and `..`, which stand for `this folder` and `this folder's parent`; those can't be suppressed, but you can strip them out of your text file (if you redirect the output of the line above to create one, of course).

For more info, type `dir /?` at a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your description of the desired output format.

But `dir /b /s /ad` will give a concise listing of an entire hierarchy, with the full path included for each folder.